# Rails. Virtual attribute (from a parent model) query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have three models: Account, Member and Child.

```
Member belongs to Account
Child belongs to Member
```

Member has an account_id attribute
Child **does not have an account_id** attribute

So I can do this...

```
Member.where(:account_id => current_user.account.id)

c = Child.last
c.member.account_id
```

In an index action, I want to list all Children that belongs to a particular account. I didn't want to add an extra `account_id` column to the `children` table.

Of course, I can't do this...

```
Child Model
def account_id
  self.member.account_id
end

Children Controller
Child.where(:account_id => current_user.account.id)
```

**Is there a way to list all children that belongs to particular account without having to add an `account_id` attribute?**

By the way, I have this on the existing query...

```
@children = Child.search(params[:search]).order(sort_column + ' ' + sort_direction).page(params[:page]).per(10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Child class, it could be done this way:

```
Child.includes(:member).where(:'members.account_id' => current_user.account.id)
```

This could be used to modify your existing query.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :members
  #This is the line you were looking for
  has_many :children, :through => :members
end

class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  has_many :children, :class_name => "Child"
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :member
end
```

Now assuming you have an accounts instance you can access all of its children by:

`account.children`